# Expand disk space on Ubuntu 10.04 (VMWare Guest)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation, disk-space-utilization, partition

I need to resize the disk space of an ubuntu guest in VMWare Workstation. After using the expand disk utility in vmware workstation, I need to do some linux magic to resize the parition. I have searched and found a lot of posts about resizing it. Unfortunately I don't really understand it all that well. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
jclawson@ubuntu:~$ df

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root
                       7583436   5678136   1520072  79% /
udev                   1030884       152   1030732   1% /dev
none                   1030884         0   1030884   0% /dev/shm
none                   1030884        72   1030812   1% /var/run
none                   1030884         0   1030884   0% /var/lock
none                   1030884         0   1030884   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda5               233335     39274    181613  18% /boot
.host:/              244035580  96519316 147516264  40% /mnt/hgfs


root@ubuntu:~# lvs
LV     VG     Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
root   ubuntu -wi-ao   7.35G
swap_1 ubuntu -wi-ao 388.00M


root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009bea5

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        1013     8136891   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda2            1014        1044      249007+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1014        1044      248976   83  Linux
```

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so after much toiling I finally figured out how to do it.  And again, gparted cannot be used.  Firstly, you should expand the size of the disk in VMWare Workstation.  Boot into a livecd and open a root terminal:

We need to create a new primary partition of type LVM out of the free unused space.

```
#fdisk /dev/sda
#Command (m for help): n
#Command (m for help): p
#Command (m for help): 3
#Command (m for help): w
```

Reboot the vm into the live cd again

Create the phyisical volume:

```
#pvcreate /dev/sda3
```

Add the new volumn to the group:

```
#vgextend ubuntu /dev/sda3
```

Find out how much free space you want to expand to

```
#vgdisplay
```

Check what "Free PE/Size" equals and use that value in the next command

Extend the lvm and grow the file system into the new space

```
#e2fsck -f /dev/ubuntu/root
#lvextend -L +12.6G /dev/ubuntu/root
#resize2fs /dev/ubuntu/root
```

Done!

Comment: +1 that sounds about right, or given this is all virtualised you could have just added a second disk and extended the lvm to that disk.

Answer (score 4):

Back up your machine.
Boot the system with [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and grow the partition.
Apply the changes.

[Here is a video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xosSvIbrylo)

Comment: gparted doesn't work on lvm's.  If you look at my post... sda1 is an LVM.

Comment: -1 It's running LVM and is virtualised, extending partitions with GParted is not the solution in this case.

Comment: +1 People who search for things like "vmware ubuntu increase disk size" will come here. The answer is helpful for some of those.